# Condition insert query in while loop in sql server

Tags: sql-server

[image]I want to insert count values in table with conditions using while loop.
I want to result like

| EmpID | EMpNo | IsActive | IsScience |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| . | . | . | . |
| 27 | 27 | 1 | 0 |
| 28 | 28 | 1 | 0 |
| . | . | . | . |
| 565 | 565 | 1 | 0 |

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < 565 
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    while @i < 26
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[T_Emp] ([EmpID],[EMpNo],[IsActive],[IsScience])
        VALUES(@i,@i,1,1);
    END
    while @i > 26 AND @i <565
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[T_Emp] ([EmpID],[EMpNo],[IsActive],[IsScience])
        VALUES(@i,@i,1,0);
    END
END
END
```

As you can see   I want to change IsScience after @i > 26 .
Also My @i isn't incremented. What I am doing wrong with looping.
My loop executing executing wrongly.

Comment: Why do you need the `while` loop?

Comment: I prefer while loop so I'm going with while loop. and i got solution thanks to Piyush Kachhadiya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove multi time while loop in your code use this code

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int = 0
    WHILE @i < 565 
    BEGIN
      SET @i = @i + 1
      IF(@i < 26)
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[T_Emp]
        ([EmpID],[EMpNo],[IsActive],[IsScience])
        VALUES(@i,@i,1,1);
      END
      IF(@i > 26 AND @i <565)
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[T_Emp]
        ([EmpID],[EMpNo],[IsActive],[IsScience])
        VALUES(@i,@i,1,0);
      END
    END
END
```